# How does relative permittivity change at high frequency?

Tags: high-frequency

I am trying to design RF radar optics for 60GHz.  However, I do not know how 'constant' the relative permittivity of a substance is.

One material I am making an RF lens out of is PEEK which measures the er at 1MHz (link to datasheet below.)

My question is in 2 parts:

1. Does anyone know of a compendium of materials with the er measured at high frequency?
2. Is it OK to assume that the er is relatively constant from 1MHz to 60GHz?  As a follow-up, what are my options to get an accurate value of er?

https://www.theplasticshop.co.uk/plastic_technical_data_sheets/peek_1000_technical_data_sheet.pdf

Comment: You definitely cannot assume that permittivity for any plastic remains constant across frequencies, especially from 1 MHz to 60 GHz. Maybe type "60 GHz radome" into your favorite search engine and see what you can learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt PEEK will work with any EHF as there are no Dk and Df or loss tangent specs and nano contaminants tend to be lossy.

Attenuation constant is linear with respect to loss tangent and can be significant contributor when tanδ ~ 0.005 - 0.01

### Getsinger effective permittivity

Equations are given in the link below along with supplier’s recommended dielectric and ultra-smooth metal layer, Astra MT.

Above a few GHz the effective Dk starts to decrease then due to surface roughness of the conductor, effective capacitance increases and thus along with that the effective Dk. But loss tangent is worse and more critical in the EHF range.

https://www.isola-group.com/wp-content/uploads/PCB-Material-Selection-for-RF-Microwave-and-Millimeter-wave-Designs-1.pdf